# python class instantiating another class

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I am having trouble figuring out how to make a menu class which will instantiate a game class in python 2.7.6 I have searched other questions related to this, but still I cannot figure out how to pass parameters from one class to another.  This is also my first time asking a question on stack overflow, so I am sorry if I incorrectly past my code in here.

```
class Lottery:
    def __init__(self, digits, betType, betAmt):
        self.digits = digits
        self.betType = betType
        self.betAmt = betAmt

    def play(self):
        print "<>" * 40
        print "Use 'mp' to play the same 'machine pick' each time"
        print "Use 'ap' to play a new 'machine pick' number each time"
        print "<>" * 40
        guess = raw_input("Choose a lottery number and see how long it takes until you win! >>")
        if guess.upper() == 'MP': #added machine pick option
            if digits == '3': #attempt support for 4 and 5 digit numbers
                choice = str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9))
            elif digits == '4':
                choice = str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9))
            elif digits == '5':
                choice = str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9))
            else:
                pass
        elif guess.upper() == 'AP': #placeholder for autopick in main loop
            pass
        else:
            choice = guess
        tries = 0
        while True:
            if guess.upper() == 'AP': #added machine pick option
                if digits == '3': #attempt support for 4 and 5 digit numbers
                    choice = str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9))
                elif digits == '4':
                    choice = str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9))
                elif digits == '5':
                    choice = str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9))
            if digits == '3': #attempt support for 4 and 5 digit numbers
                winning = str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9))
            elif digits == '4':
                winning = str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9))
            elif digits == '5':
                winning = str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9)) + str(randint(0,9))
            print winning, choice
            tries += 1
            if digits == '3':
                time.sleep(0.02)
            elif digits == '4':
                time.sleep(0.002)
            else:
                time.sleep(0.0005)
            if winning == choice:
                print "-----" * 10
                print "winner after " + str(tries) + " tries!"
                print "It took you " + str(tries/2) + " days to win!"
                print "your tickets cost $" + str(tries) + ".00"
                print "Your payout was $500"
                print "Your Net Revenue was $" + str(500 - tries) + ".00"
                print "-----" * 10
                break
```

and

```
class Menu:
    def __init__(self):
        #self.game = Lottery(digits, betType, betAmt)
        self.start()
    def start(self):
        print "Welcome to the Lottery!"
        self.digits = raw_input("Would you like to play '3' digit, '4' digit, or '5' digit? >> ")
        self.betType = raw_input("Straight, or Boxed bet type? >> ")
        self.betAmt = raw_input("$0.50, or $1.00? >> ")
        self.game = Lottery(self.digits, self.betType, self.betAmt)
        self.game.play()
        raw_input("Enter to play again")
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am new to Python and also Stack Overflow.  Thanks :)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ILR2.py", line 81, in <module>
    Menu1 = Menu()
  File "ILR2.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.start()
  File "ILR2.py", line 78, in start
    self.game.play()
  File "ILR2.py", line 38, in play
    if digits == '3': #attempt support for 4 and 5 digit numbers
NameError: global name 'digits' is not defined
```

This is the error I am getting when trying to run the program.  Does this help? Sorry I forgot to post the first time

Comment: What is the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: The code snippet is incomplete and produces a traceback that there is no `play` method for your `Lottery` class.  You'll have to write that method, or provide more complete code so we can assist further.

Comment: Agree with @g.d.d.c... Show what the `play` method does, please **:-)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with how you're instantiating the lottery class. That part is fine. Rather, it looks your `play` method in your `Lottery` class is buggy.

We can see this from looking at your exception:

```
File "ILR2.py", line 38, in play
    if digits == '3': #attempt support for 4 and 5 digit numbers
NameError: global name 'digits' is not defined
```

Based on context, it looks like you're trying to access the `digits` attribute. In order to do that, you need to use `self`:

```
if self.digits == '3':
    pass
```

Comment: You probably meant `self.digits`, as `play` is a function of class `Lottery`

Answer (score 1):

I think in this situation it might not make sense to have a separate class for your menu. After all, you are storing the same information about your game in the `Menu` class and in the `Lottery` class.

You could simplify it quite a bit by adding the menu as a method within your `Lottery` class. Then you would not need to pass around the variables, since they are provided by the user's input anyways:

```
class Lottery:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.showMenu()
        self.play()

    def showMenu(self):
        # this is the code from your Menu class
        print "Welcome to the Lottery!"
        self.digits = raw_input("Would you like to play '3' digit, '4' digit, or '5' digit? >> ")
        self.betType = raw_input("Straight, or Boxed bet type? >> ")
        self.betAmt = raw_input("$0.50, or $1.00? >> ")

    def play(self):
        # gameplay code as before
```

Answer (score 0):

I am NOT sure, as I can't see the code for the `play()` function, but it looks like you should use `self.digits`, not `digits` there. Just a guess thought.